# C# method invocation on generic object via action/delegate (kotlin example)

Tags: c#, generics, kotlin, action

I would like to invoke method calls on generic object in C#. Can't seem to figure out how I would do this. I will post a kotlin example how I have done this for the MVP pattern in our android app.

Base presenter generic implementation:

```
interface IBasePresenter<in T> {
    fun takeView(view: T)
    fun dropView()
}

class BasePresenter<T> : IBasePresenter<T> {
    private var view: T? = null

    final override fun takeView(view: T) {
        this.view = view
    }

    final override fun dropView() {
        view = null
    }

    fun onView(action: T.() -> Unit) {
        if (view != null) {
            action.invoke(view!!) // Magic :-)
        }
    }
}
```

Simple contract for MVP implementation:

```
interface IMyView {
    fun doSomeRendering(int width, int height)
}

interface IMyPresenter : IBasePresenter<IMyView> {
    fun onButtonClicked()
}
```

Implementation of view and presenter:

```
class MyView : Fragment(), IMyView {
    ....

    override fun doSomeRendering(int width, int height) {
        // Do some rendering with width and height...
    }

    ....
}

class MyPresenter : BasePresenter<IMyView> {
    override fun onButtonClicked() {
        // onView action block is context aware of IMyView functions...
        onView { doSomeRendering(800, 400) } // Magic :-)
    }
}
```

I have everything setup in C# besides the following:

```
fun onView(action: T.() -> Unit) {
    if (view != null) {
        action.invoke(view!!)
    }
}
```

Can this be done in C# just like in kotlin ?
All I need is to be able to perform the following call in the concrete presenter implementation,

```
onView { doSomeRendering(800, 400) }
```

that way I can keep my view private in BasePresenter and not expose it to the concrete implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I only started learning Kotlin last weekend.  I'm not sure what `(action: T.() -> Unit)` means (specifcally `T.()`) In C# you want to do something like `void OnView(Action<T> action) {     action?.(view); }` yes?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to do this. The following code is for C#:

Base presenter implementation:

```
void OnView(Action<TView> action) => action(_view)
```

Invocation from concrete presenter implementation:

```
OnView(view => view.DoSomeRendering(800, 400))
```

And so the view no longer need to be protected in base presenter and can be private.